# Setting up database for Heroku using Laravel. Where to put my DB credentials

Tags: php, laravel, heroku

I'm currently using the ff:

- Laravel 7.0
- Heroku for deployment
- JawsDB for the DB add-on (add-on provided by Heroku)
- DB add-on is managed by my HeidiSQL using the credentials of JawsDB.

Now, JawsDB [provided](https://i.stack.imgur.com/iCXTa.png) me with a **DB connection string**. reading the Laravel docs, I could use the **DB connection string** (or also called URL in the Laravel docs) to add the DB credentials provided by JawsDB for me (host, username & pw, port, DB name). The problem with the [docs (see "Configuration Using URLs" section)](https://laravel.com/docs/7.x/database) is that it didn't provide me a way of how to put the **DB connection string**, but it does tell me to put it in `config/database.php` section.

My site's up and accessible on the landing page, but I'm really not connected with my DB.

So, my question is this:

- how to insert my **DB connection string/URL** in the `config/database.php` so that I could use my DB?
- [looking](https://i.stack.imgur.com/66jL4.png) at the `config/database.php` section and comparing with the DB credentials provided by the JawsDB, it seems like JawsDB doesnt have the unix socket and the `MYSQL_ATTR_SSL_CA`. is it necessary to put or not?

Comment: you should surf more, [How to Host a Laravel App with MySQL Database on Heroku](https://medium.com/@nedsoft/how-to-host-a-laravel-app-with-mysql-database-on-heroku-ab56b08be735), and this is one of the many